# Shift position from the first to the last

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a simple program that shift the position of the first to the last until a:
1  2  3  4  5  6
Looks like:
6  5  4  3  2  1

IDK why the second for doesn´t work.

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x[6], a = 6, safe = 0;
    cout<<"Value"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        cin>>x[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i != 2; ++i) {
        safe = x[i];
        x[i] = x[a];
        x[a] = safe;
        a --;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        cout<<"[ "<<x[i]<<" ]"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `a=6` on initial condition in the first iteration of your second loop, and your array `x `only has 6 elements, then `x[a]` is already out of bounds.  What do you get with `a=5` ?

Comment: it's a reversal or mirroring, not a shift

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Problems:**

1. `x[a]` access an element out of bonds during the first iteration, what itself is Undefined Behaviour.
2. `for (int i = 0; i != 2; ++i)` does not make sense at all. Why the condition would be `i != 2`.

**Solution:**

Instead of making yourself a lot of trouble you can just reverse the array with `std::reverse` (Documentation for `std::reverse` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)).

If you want to make it manually it is easier than you think. Just replace the second `for` loop with this:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < length/2; ++i)
        std::swap(x[i],x[length-i-1]);
```

This traverses the array with a single variable and swaps the values in the left with the values in the right.

**Additional information:**

1. `safe` variable is never used. You should delete it.
2. You may use `std::array` instead of raw C arrays (Documentation for `std::array` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)).
3. `using namespace std;` is considered a bad practice (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).

**Full code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    constexpr int length = 6;
    int x[length];
    std::cout << "Value" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        std::cin >> x[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < length/2; ++i)
        std::swap(x[i],x[length-i-1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        std::cout<<"[ "<<x[i]<<" ]"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```